# How to break text in a line in a div by css?

Tags: css

How can we break text if we have limited width of a div,However I have parent div,which has also same width,Please suggest how can we achive it by CSS?

Comment: Text gets formatted on more than one line as needed, by default. What exactly do you mean? Please show an example of content and code, and explain what you would like to change in the rendering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi now used to this

**as like this**

```
div{
white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/R7pel370)***

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your div

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: @Himanhu_cool, Check this url:  [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with with [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

```
div.yourBox {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```